# PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage stored in RAM appears as black square on Tkinter

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Ok so I'm trying to reproduce a raycaster with Python. All things done, now  I've got a 512x512 matrix coded as 8-bit colors, that I try rendering through Tkinter.

Problem is, after doing a bit of conversion with Pillow, the image appears roughly half-sized, but most importantly as a black square. I'm sure it's some kind of misuse of a function, but i can't find which. Here's the code :

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np

fen = Tk.Tk()
img = plt.imread('BG0.png')
canvas = Tk.Canvas(fen, width = 512, height = 512)
canvas.pack()

def Up(event):
   global img
   i = np.finfo(img.dtype)
   img = img.astype(np.float64)/i.max
   img = 255 * img
   img = img.astype(np.uint8)
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))
   canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = img, anchor = Tk.NW)

fen.bind_all('<Up>', Up)
fen.mainloop()
```

And here's that famous image we're looking to show (but actually, any 512x512 image could do the trick i'd say), just put it in the same folder as this program:
[BG0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1scmf.png)

You just have to press the up arrow key on your keybord to have it render in the tkinter window.

Comment: You know that you are using the variable `img` for 2 different datatypes, right? So The second time you `Up` function is called, it will most likely raise an error

Comment: No errors on my side, i just change the datatype through the program
Do you think that's the cause of the problem ?
I've tried changing the two last instances of 'img' to 'image', but it now returns an error (exception in tkinter callback [...] ValueError: data type <class 'numpy.uint8'> not inexact)

Comment: Why don't you move all of the image preparations as in everything from `i = np.finfo(img.dtype)` to `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))` (including both) outside of the function?

Comment: Well, actually, the image is raycasted everytime the functions starts in a subfile (with a set frequency to not overflow the RAM), so i can't really only do this once before and be done with it

Comment: Your imports are quite weird. Using `Tk` as `tkinter`.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem of tkinter, looks like there is something wrong with your image functions

Comment: I know there’s a problem at some point in the conversions, the problem being that I can’t really test those and print them for example as matrixes to know exactly at which point it stops doing what I want it to, as Pillow images can’t be rendered in the shell (only the type/location is displayed)

Answer (score 0):

It's a PIL and Tkinter bug.

The image that ImageTk returns must to be stored in a variable, or a list.

You can try to pop one image from the list and it will disappear.

Here is what you can do.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np

fen = Tk.Tk()
img = plt.imread('BG0.png')
canvas = Tk.Canvas(fen, width = 512, height = 512)
canvas.pack()

# THIS IS NEEDED
images_tk_list = []
 
def Up(event):
   global img
   i = np.finfo(img.dtype)
   img = img.astype(np.float64)/i.max
   img = 255 * img
   img = img.astype(np.uint8)
   img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))

   # THIS IS NEEDED
   images_tk_list.append( img )

   canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = img, anchor = Tk.NW)

fen.bind_all('<Up>', Up)
fen.mainloop()
```